How to Open a Cadence Allegro 16.3 .BRD File without Access to Full Software?
I’m working on a project involving Texas Instruments’ AM335x ICE Board, and I downloaded their .BRD file for the PCB layout. Unfortunately, this file was saved in Cadence Allegro version 16.3, and I only have access to the Allegro Free Physical Viewer.
When I try to open the file, I get an error message:
“The current version of software is unable to open design… The design was last saved using version 16.3 and must be updated using DB Doctor.”
I understand that DB Doctor (part of the full Cadence Allegro software) is required to update the file to a compatible version, but I don’t have access to it.
My Questions:
Are there any alternative tools or methods to open or convert .BRD files from Allegro 16.3 without the full software?
Does anyone know of any open-source or trial software that might allow me to convert it to a more accessible format (e.g., Gerber or KiCad-compatible)?
Has anyone had success using third-party tools to open older .BRD files?
I’d appreciate any guidance or recommendations.
Note: The file is available from Texas Instruments here: https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/tidc179

"Allegro Free Physical Viewer" is the right tool, you just need to find an older version of it that will support 16.3 .brd files.

Version 16.6 of the free viewer will open it (screenshot). There is a download from archive.org of that version - note this is not an endorsment, you will need to do due dilligance to decide whether to trust downloading software from there, or e-mail Cadence and see if they can send you a copy.
